# Test Class for Apex Controller Class

Tags: apex

This is my first test class for Apex Controller. Here is my whole scenario
1. I have a VF page which loads Quotes in a list which can be selected
2. On this page, user can select the quotes and click  a button to generate a PDF page which is different VF page. the functionality works perfectly fine. Now I am writing the test class and able to pass through Constructor function. But not sure how to write the test class for Display function. I have added all three controllers here which are the part of both of the VF page and test class written so far

Class list Quotes and provides option for selection

```
    public class MyQuoteListCntrlr{
         // PROPERTIES
         public List<QuoteWrapperCls> quoteList {get;set;}
         public List<QQuoteWrapperCls > QquoteList{get;set;}

         public List<QuoteIncludeWP> QuoteIncludes{get;set;}
         public Set<String> selQuoteAppId{get;set;}
         public Set<String> selQuoteDecId{get;set;}
         public string HTMLString {get;set;}
         public Boolean hasSelQuote {get;set;}

         Date myDate = system.today();

         public Opportunity oppData {get; set;}
         public Opportunity oppPData {get; set;}

            // PROPERTIES

         public Quote_Application__c qquoteData {get; set;}
         public LIST<Quote> AppQuote {get;set;}
         public LIST<Quote> DecQuote {get;set;}

        public Datetime ToDayDate {get; set;}
        public  String dateOutput {get; set;}


         // CONSTRUCTOR
         public MyQuoteListCntrlr(ApexPages.StandardController controller){




                Id recordId = controller.getId();



                oppData =[Select Id,Name, account.name, Owner.Name, Physical_Address_Street__c, Physical_Address_City__c, Physical_Address_State__c, Physical_Address_Zip__c, First_Name__c, Last_Name__C from Opportunity where id=:recordId ];



              quoteList = new List<QuoteWrapperCls>();



              for(Quote a : [SELECT ID, QuoteNumber, Status,Carrier__c, Account__c,DownPayment__c,Down_Payment_Taken__c, MonthlyPayments__c, Premium_Amount__c
              FROM Quote where status in ('Carrier Approved','Carrier Declined')  and opportunityid =: oppData.Id
              ]){
                   quoteList.add(new QuoteWrapperCls(a));
              }

              QquoteList= new List<QQuoteWrapperCls >(); 


              for(Quote_Application__c QQ : [SELECT ID,Name, Dot__c,Docket__c, Email__c FROM Quote_Application__c where OpportunityQuickQuote__c=: oppData.Id order by LastModifiedDate LIMIT 1
              ]){
                   QquoteList.add(new QQuoteWrapperCls (QQ ));
              }

         }


                 public PageReference Display()

                 {
                    String ProposalIdAppr;
                    String ProposalIdDec;
                    selQuoteAppId= new Set<String>();
                    selQuoteAppId.clear();

                    selQuoteDecId= new Set<String>();
                    selQuoteDecId.clear();
                    Integer Count;
                    Count=0;

                     ProposalIdAppr= Datetime.now().format('mm-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS');
                     for(QuoteWrapperCls cWrapper : quoteList){
                     if(cWrapper.isSelected && cWrapper.cQuote.Status=='Carrier Approved'){

                        ProposalQuotes__c ProposalQuote = new ProposalQuotes__c(); 
                        ProposalQuote.ProposalID__c =  ProposalIdAppr;  
                        ProposalQuote.QuoteID__c    =cWrapper.cQuote.Id  ;

                        insert ProposalQuote ;

                        Count = count +1;


                   }}

                    ToDayDate = Datetime.now();
                    ProposalIdDec = Datetime.now().format('mm-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS');
              for(QuoteWrapperCls cWrapperDec : quoteList){
                   if(cWrapperDec.isSelected && cWrapperDec.cQuote.Status=='Carrier Declined'){

                        ProposalQuotes__c ProposalQuote = new ProposalQuotes__c(); 
                        ProposalQuote.ProposalID__c =  ProposalIdDec;  
                        ProposalQuote.QuoteID__c    =cWrapperDec.cQuote.Id  ;

                        insert ProposalQuote ;
                         Count = count +1;
                   }}
                   If (Count ==0)
                   {
                       Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error,''+'No Quote has been selected for proposal"'));
                       return page.proposalform;
                   }  


                        PageReference pdf = new PageReference('/apex/proposal?Id=' + oppData.Id + '&ProposalIdAppr=' + ProposalIdAppr + '&ProposalIdDec=' + ProposalIdDec); 


                              pdf.setredirect(true);
                            // need to pass unit test -- current bug   








                      return pdf;

                             }

            }


public class QQuoteWrapperCls {
     public Boolean isSelected {get;set;}
     public Quote_Application__c cQQuote {get;set;}

     public QQuoteWrapperCls(Quote_Application__c cQQuote ){
          this.cQQuote = cQQuote ;
     }
}


public class MyProposalCntrlr{
// PROPERTIES
     public List<QuoteWrapperCls> quoteList {get;set;}
     public List<QQuoteWrapperCls > QquoteList{get;set;}

     public List<QuoteIncludeWP> QuoteIncludes{get;set;}
     public Set<String> selQuoteAppId{get;set;}
     public Set<String> selQuoteDecId{get;set;}
     public string HTMLString {get;set;}
     public Boolean hasSelQuote {get;set;}
     public String StrId{get;set;}

     Date myDate = system.today();


     public Opportunity oppData {get; set;}

        // PROPERTIES

     public Quote_Application__c qquoteData {get; set;}
     public LIST<Quote> AppQuote {get;set;}
     public LIST<Quote> DecQuote {get;set;}

    public Datetime ToDayDate {get; set;}
    public  String dateOutput {get; set;}
     public LIST<Commodities_transported__c> ctData {get; set;}
     public LIST<Driver__c> DriverData {get; set;}
     public LIST<Garage__c> GarageData {get; set;}
     public LIST<Vehicle__c> VehicleData {get; set;}
     public String selQuoteSelected {get; set;}


     // CONSTRUCTOR
     public MyProposalCntrlr(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
           selQuoteAppId= new Set<String>();
            selQuoteAppId.clear();

            selQuoteDecId= new Set<String>();
            selQuoteDecId.clear();


            Id recordId = controller.getId();


             controller.addFields(new String[]{

                'Id', 'Name', 'account.name', 'Owner.Name', 'Owner.Email', 'Owner.Extension', 'Physical_Address_Street__c', 'Physical_Address_City__c', 'Physical_Address_State__c', 'Physical_Address_Zip__c', 'First_Name__c', 'Last_Name__C'

            });
            oppData = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();


            LIST<ProposalQuotes__c> ProposalApprQuote ;

            ProposalApprQuote = [select QuoteID__c   From ProposalQuotes__c where ProposalID__c =:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('ProposalIdAppr')];

            for(ProposalQuotes__c cWrapper : ProposalApprQuote ){


                    selQuoteAppId.add( cWrapper.QuoteID__c);


                }


              LIST<ProposalQuotes__c> ProposalDecQuote ;
                 ProposalDecQuote = [select QuoteID__c  From ProposalQuotes__c where ProposalID__c =:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('ProposalIdDec')];

                for(ProposalQuotes__c cWrapperDec : ProposalDecQuote ){


                    selQuoteDecId.add( cWrapperDec.QuoteID__c);


                }

           ToDayDate = Datetime.now();
           dateOutput = ToDayDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy');

           AppQuote  = [Select id, name, carrier__r.name,    Effective_Date_of_Policy__c,  Of_Payments__c,Auto_Liability__c,BOP__c,General_Liability__c,Cargo__c,CPP__c,DownPayment__c, MonthlyPayments__c,Physical_Damage__c, PL_Auto__c,PL_Home__c,PL_Umbrella__c,Premium_Amount__c,Transporter_Plate__c,Umbrella__c,Workers_Compensation__c,Garage_Keepers__c from Quote where id in:selQuoteAppId];
                HTMLString  ='';
           for (Quote Q : AppQuote  )
           {
            String EffectiveDate ='';
            IF(Q.Effective_Date_of_Policy__c <> null)
            {
               ToDayDate =Q.Effective_Date_of_Policy__c;

                EffectiveDate =  ToDayDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy');
            }
            HTMLString =HTMLString + '   <div style="width:700px; font-size:14px; padding-top:25px;  border-bottom:1px solid #000;font-weight:bold">Quote - '+  q.Carrier__r.name  + '</div> ';
            HTMLString =HTMLString + '<table><tr > <td Colspan ="8"></td></tr><tr><td style="color:#0b0b3b; font-size:12px; width:800px; padding-bottom:1px; padding-top:5px;" Colspan ="8"><b>Premium/Payment Information:</b></td>';
            HTMLString =HTMLString + '</tr><tr><td style="color:#0b0b3b; font-size:12px; padding-top:10px;"><b>Premium Amount: </b></td> <td style="color:#0b0b3b; font-size:12px;  ; padding-top:10px;"> $' + q.Premium_Amount__c  + '</td>' ;
            HTMLString =HTMLString  + '<td style="color:#0b0b3b; font-size:12px; padding-top:10px;" ><b>Monthly Payment: </b></td>';
            HTMLString =HTMLString  + '   <td style="color:#0b0b3b; font-size:12px; padding-top:10px;"> $' + q.MonthlyPayments__c  + '</td>';

             HTMLString =HTMLString  + '   <td style="color:#0b0b3b; font-size:12px; padding-top:10px;"><b>Down Payment: </b></td>';
             HTMLString =HTMLString  + '   <td style="color:#0b0b3b; font-size:12px;  padding-top:10px;"> $'+ Q.DownPayment__c +'</td>';
              HTMLString =HTMLString  + '   <td style="color:#0b0b3b; font-size:12px; padding-top:10px;" ><b># of Payment: </b></td>';
              HTMLString =HTMLString  + '  <td style="color:#0b0b3b; font-size:12px; padding-top:10px;">'+ Q.Of_Payments__c + '</td> </tr>';
              HTMLString =HTMLString + '<tr > <td Colspan ="8"></td></tr><tr><td style="color:#0b0b3b; font-size:12px; width:800px; padding-bottom:1px; padding-top:5px;" Colspan ="8"><b>Effective Date Of Policy: ' +  EffectiveDate + '</b></td>';
              HTMLString =HTMLString + '<tr > <td Colspan ="8"></td></tr><tr><td style="color:#0b0b3b; font-size:12px; width:800px; padding-bottom:1px; padding-top:5px;" Colspan ="8"><b>Quote Includes:</b></td>';
               QuoteIncludes= new List<QuoteIncludeWP>();
              if (Q.Auto_Liability__c ==true)
              {
                  QuoteIncludes.add(new QuoteIncludeWP('Auto Liability:',Q.Auto_Liability__c));  
                  }
              if (Q.BOP__c ==true)
              {
              QuoteIncludes.add(new QuoteIncludeWP('BOP:',Q.BOP__c));
              }
              if (Q.Cargo__c ==true)
              {
                  QuoteIncludes.add(new QuoteIncludeWP('Cargo:',Q.Cargo__c));
              }
              if (Q.CPP__c ==true)
              {
                  QuoteIncludes.add(new QuoteIncludeWP('CPP:',Q.CPP__c)); 
              }
              if (Q.Physical_Damage__c ==true)
              {
                  QuoteIncludes.add(new QuoteIncludeWP('Physical Damage:',Q.Physical_Damage__c)); 
              }
              if (Q.Auto_Liability__c ==true)
              {
                  QuoteIncludes.add(new QuoteIncludeWP('Garage Keepers:',Q.Auto_Liability__c)); 
              }
              if (Q.Umbrella__c ==true)
              {
                  QuoteIncludes.add(new QuoteIncludeWP('Umbrella:',Q.Umbrella__c)); 
              }
              if (Q.Transporter_Plate__c ==true)
              {
                  QuoteIncludes.add(new QuoteIncludeWP('Transporter Plate:',Q.Transporter_Plate__c)); 
              }
               if (Q.General_Liability__c ==true)
              {
                  QuoteIncludes.add(new QuoteIncludeWP('General Liability:',Q.General_Liability__c)); 
              }
           if (Q.PL_Auto__c ==true)
              { 
                  QuoteIncludes.add(new QuoteIncludeWP('PL - Auto:',Q.PL_Auto__c)); 
              }
            if (Q.Workers_Compensation__c ==true)
              { 
              QuoteIncludes.add(new QuoteIncludeWP('Workers Compensation:',Q.Workers_Compensation__c)); 
              }
            if (Q.PL_Home__c ==true)
              { 
              QuoteIncludes.add(new QuoteIncludeWP('PL - Home:',Q.PL_Home__c)); 
              }
           if (Q.PL_Umbrella__c ==true)
              { QuoteIncludes.add(new QuoteIncludeWP('PL - Umbrella:',Q.PL_Umbrella__c));
              }


              integer ColCount=0;
               Integer remainder ;
              for (QuoteIncludeWP QI : QuoteIncludes)

              {

                ColCount = ColCount +1;
                remainder = math.mod(ColCount, 4);
                  if (remainder  ==1)
                   {
                       HTMLString = HTMLString + '<tr>';
                  }
                   HTMLString = HTMLString + '<td style="color:#0b0b3b; font-size:12px; padding-top:10px;"><b>' + QI.lblName + '  </b></td> <td style="color:#0b0b3b; font-size:12px;  ; padding-top:10px;">' + + QI.lblValue+  + '</td>' ;

                   if (remainder  ==0)
                   {                       HTMLString = HTMLString + '</tr>';
                   }
              }
                       HTMLString = HTMLString + '</tr>   </table> ';
           }

          DecQuote = [Select id, name, carrier__r.name,   DeclinedReason__c from Quote where status ='Carrier Declined' and id in:selQuoteDecId]; 

        // oppData = [Select Id,Name, account.name, Owner.Name, Physical_Address_Street__c, Physical_Address_City__c, Physical_Address_State__c, Physical_Address_Zip__c, First_Name__c, Last_Name__C from Opportunity where id =:oppid ];




     qquotedata =   [SELECT Id, 
                     Name, Leads__c, 
                     Contacct_Agent__c, 
                     Agency__c, 
                     Email__c, 
                     PercentageSum__c,
                     QuoteApplicationDate__c, 
                     InsuredBusinessName__c, 
                     Street__c, 
                     City__c, 
                     Zip__c, 
                     State__c, 
                     InsuredPhoneNo__c, 
                    InsuredEmail__c, 
                     PrincipleOwnerName__c, 
                     Mailingaddress__c, 
                     MailingCity__c, 
                     Mailing_State__c, 
                     MailingZip__c, 
                     BusinessCell__c, 
                     BusinessFax__c, 
                     AlternateEmail__c, 
                     EIN__c, 
                     DOB__c,
                     OwnerId ,
                     CTCount__c, 
                     DriverCount__c, 
                     GarageCount__c, 
                     VehicleCount__c,
                     Social_Security__c, Cargo_Limit__c, Cargo_Deductable__c, Date_obtained_CDL__c,Drivers_License__c,  Drivers_License_State__c,
                     UM__c, UIM__c, PIP__c, Refrigeretor_Breakdown__c, Trailer_Interchange__c, Do_you_have_copy_of_contract__c, 
                     Trailer_Interchange_Limit__c, Non_owned_Trailer__c, NonOwnedTrailerLimit__c, CGL__c, UMB__c, WorkerCompensation__c, 
                     EstimatedPayrolExposure__c, CGLOccuranceLimit__c, CGLAggreegate__c, UMBOccuranceLimit__c, UMBAggregateLimit__c, CarrierOffering__c, 
                     CurrentPremium__c, Target_Premium__c, Carrier_Operation__c, Comments__c, OpportunityQuickQuote__c, OperationClassification__c, UM_PD__c, 
                     MedicalPayment__c, Docket__c, DOT__c, Liability__c, BusinessStartedYear__c ,No_Email__c
                     FROM Quote_Application__c where OpportunityQuickQuote__c =:oppData.Id order by LastModifiedDate LIMIT 1];
                      CTData =[SELECT Cargo_Info__c, Freight_percent__c,    Max_Value__c, Avg_Value__c FROM Commodities_transported__c WHERE Quote_Application__c =:qquotedata.ID];

                      DriverData =[SELECT Name_del__c, CDL_Year__c, Accidents__c, DateOfHire__c, DOB__c, License__c, State__c, Type__c, Violations__c from Driver__c WHERE Quote_Application__c =:qquotedata.ID];

                      GarageData =[SELECT City__c, Street__c,   Zip__c, State__c, Garage__c.Name  FROM Garage__c WHERE QuoteApplication__c =:qquotedata.ID];

                      VehicleData =[SELECT Name, CurrentValue__c, Deductable__c,    Garage__c,  GVWR__c, Make_Model__c, Radius__c, Safety_Device__c, Type__c, VIN__c, Year__c FROM vehicle__c WHERE Quote_Application__c =:qquotedata.ID]; 






         } 
               public pagereference saveAttach()

        {

                 //system.debug('The url created is' + pdf);

                 String ProposalIdAppr =apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('ProposalIdAppr');
                 String ProposalIdDec =apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('ProposalIdDec');
                    // create the new attachment */
                   Attachment attach = new Attachment(); 
                    Blob body;

                   PageReference pdf = new PageReference('/apex/proposalclone?Id=' + oppData.Id + '&ProposalIdAppr=' + ProposalIdAppr + '&ProposalIdDec=' + ProposalIdDec); 

                     // returns the output of the page as a PDFclone

                        system.debug('body should be fine');
                         pdf.setredirect(true);
                        // need to pass unit test -- current bug   
                         try { 
         body = pdf.getContentAsPDF(); 
      } catch (VisualforceException e) {
        body = Blob.valueOf('Some Text');
    }
        attach.Body = body;
        // add the user entered name
        attach.Name = oppData.Name + ' ' + myDate + '.pdf';
        attach.IsPrivate = false;
         //attach the pdf to the account
        attach.ParentId = oppData.Id;
        insert attach; 
return pdf;
        }

         }
```

**Test Class written so far**

```
@isTest 
public class TestMyQuoteListCntrlr{
    static testMethod void MyQuoteListCntrlrCons() 
    {
       Account  Acct = new Account();

       Acct.Name ='My Test Account';

       insert Acct;

       Opportunity Opp = new Opportunity ();

       // Do you recognize these fields?
       Opp.Name= 'Test';
       Opp.Account= Acct ;
       Opp.Amount= 0;
       Opp.CloseDate= System.today() ;
       Opp.StageName= 'Negotiation';

       insert Opp;




      Quote Qt= new Quote();


       // Do you recognize these fields?
       Qt.Name= 'Test';
       Qt.Opportunity= Opp ;
       Qt.Opportunityid= Opp.id ;
       Qt.Carrier__c= Acct.id;
       Qt.Account__c= Acct.id;
       Qt.Status= 'Carrier Approved' ;
       Qt.Billing_Type__c= 'Paid In Full';
       Qt.MonthlyPayments__c= 400;
       Qt.Premium_Amount__c= 300;
       Qt.DownPayment__c= 200 ;
       Qt.Down_Payment_Taken__c= 100;
       Qt.Of_Payments__c =10;
       Qt.Auto_Liability__c =True;
       Qt.Effective_Date_of_Policy__c =date.ValueOf('2016-02-02');
       Qt.DateQuoteReqSent__c =date.ValueOf('2016-02-02');
       Qt.DateQuoteReceived__c =date.ValueOf('2016-02-01');
     Qt.ExpirationDate =date.ValueOf('2016-02-01');
       insert Qt;


        Quote Qt1= new Quote();
        // Do you recognize these fields?
       Qt1.Name= 'Test1';
       Qt1.Opportunity= Opp  ;
       Qt1.Opportunityid= Opp.id ;
       Qt1.Carrier__c= Acct.id;
       Qt1.Account__c= Acct.id;
       Qt1.Status= 'Carrier Declined' ;
       Qt1.DeclinedReason__c      ='Chameleon Carrier';       

       insert Qt1;

        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(opp);
        MyQuoteListCntrlr ctl = new MyQuoteListCntrlr ( sc); 


    }
    }
```

Comment: Add `ctl.display()` after you instantiated the controller in the test class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ctl.display() after you instantiated the controller in the test class

```
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(opp);
        MyQuoteListCntrlr ctl = new MyQuoteListCntrlr ( sc); 
ctl.display();
```